# Can Raspberry Pi OS images be run under Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, virtualization, arm, raspberry-pi

I've ordered a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org), but I'm on a long lead time and I'd like to start playing today!

I've downloaded the disc image, tried to boot it in Windows 7 Virtual PC and it doesn't work. Of course, it's because those images are built for the ARM CPU and I'm running a 64-bit version of windows 7.

So, I think the root of my question is, can I run a virtual PC which emulates a different CPU architecture under Windows?

I'll happily change the Virtual PC software I'm running! I expect that's essential.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

G

Comment: I know [QEmu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) can emulate an ARM on your PC. I don't know if it's close enough to the RPi to allow you to run RPi software. (Yes, [it can be made to work](http://www.cnx-software.com/2012/02/18/raspberry-pi-releases-1st-sd-card-image-debian-how-to-use-it-in-the-emulator/), at least on Linux.)

Comment: This is going to take some serious reading!

Comment: try using the development vm that can be found here http://russelldavis.org/2012/01/20/new-raspberry-pi-development-vm-v0-2/ . i havn't tried it yet but maybe it will work for what you need.

Comment: Please note there is a Raspberry Pi proposal on Area 51.  Please follow if you have not done so already ... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37041/raspberry-pi-hardware-and-software

Comment: I've committed to the proposal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work: [Emulating Raspberry Pi in Windows the easy way](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5743)

Direct link to download: [Raspberry Pi emulation for Windows](http://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/)

Just download the folder, unzip and run the batch file – then follow the supplied instructions to login etc.

Comment: Just trying this now

Comment: Works flawlessly!

Comment: ...but have not been updated since.

Answer (score 2):

I got both the latest Debian and ArchLinux images to load using QEMU running under Windows 7 x64 with the following command lines:

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda debian6-19-04-2012.img -clock dynticks
```

and

```
qemu-system-arm -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -M versatilepb -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1" -hda archlinuxarm-19-04-2012.img -clock dynticks
```

Just grab the [latest QEMU binaries](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/) and [download the distributions](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/).

EDIT: The kernel I got to work was the kernel.img file from the SD Card image of the Debian distribution. I had to copy this file from the SD card to the QEMU program directory.

Comment: Hi, this answer looks the most promising so far but unfortunately didn't work straight out. The installer didn't include qemu-system-arm.exe I've grabbed the files individually from the folder but now get "kernel-qemu: No such file or directory

I cant find any kernel files on that repository
qemu: could not load kernel 'kernel-qemu'"

Comment: Is it looking for a kernel within the image file?

Comment: I copied the kernal from the SD card image I have for the RPi and it now seems to be running. just need to get VNC to connect to it now!

Comment: Sorry I had to accept John's answer as it is so much simpler. Thank you for your help!